# Suggestion for template book for C++?

Tags: c++, templates, resources

I am learning templates. Which book is worth buying for doing template programming?

I already have [The C++ Programming Language](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_C%2B%2B_Programming_Language) and [Effective C++](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scott_Meyers#Publications).

Comment: Duplicate of [The Definitive C++ Book Guide and List](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list) (there is no need for more than one C++ book list)

Answer (score 45, accepted):

Those two books are pretty good in my opinion and they helped me a lot

> - [*C++ Templates: The Complete Guide* by David Vandevoorde and Nicolai M.
>     Josuttis](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0201734842)
> - [*Modern C++ Design* by Andrei Alexandrescu](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0201704315)

The first one explains how templates work. The second book is more about *how* to use them. I recommend you to read the first book before starting with Modern C++ Design because that's heavy stuff.

Comment: Modern C++ Design is absolutely brilliant. Not only will you pick up wonderful programming tips, you'll also learn how to keep your code simple.

Answer (score 10):

Maybe a bit mind-boggling if you are just learning, but after the books you mention, you may want to read Andrei Alexandrescu's [Modern C++ Design](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0201704315), if only to learn what can be accomplished through templates.  Besides, it discusses many advanced aspects of templates wonderfully.

Comment: Modern C++ is crazy, but it's the best.

Comment: I've read it twice so far. Each time a little more sticks in my brain. I guess it's time for a third reading ;-)

Comment: Thanks for fixing the typo, Ferruccio.

Answer (score 8):

Search for fairly recent book ["Advanced C++ Metaprogramming" by Davide Di Gennaro](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1460966163)

Answer (score 5):

Both [Modern C++ design](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0201704315) and [C++ Template Metaprogramming](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321227255) are very good (and quite advanced) books on the subject. I have a strong personal preference for the first.

Answer (score 2):

[C++ Templates: The Complete Guide](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0201734842) is your best bet. You could also learn about the [Standard Library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/171802/where-can-i-learn-about-the-c-standard-template-library-stl/) which heavily uses templates.

Answer (score 1):

["C++ Templates: The Complete Guide (Vandevoorde & Josuttis)"](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0201734842) is excellent for the theory.
Then you can learn even more about actual templating practice by looking at how templates are used in the [Boost library](http://www.boost.org/).

Answer (score 1):

There is a hidden treasure in C++ templates that very few people are aware of: [C++ Common Knowledge: Essential Intermediate Programming](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321321928).

The last 15 chapters of that book both teaches better and complements *C++ Template Metaprogramming* in some respects. I strongly recommend anyone who is to learn templates to read this book foremost.

Answer (score 0):

[Effective STL](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0201749629) by Scott Meyers